# Using List or Collection to Seed data with EF Code First

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable, ilist

I'm adding some seed data for my development database.  What I have seems rather clunky, is there a way to use some sort of IEnumerable type such as List or perhaps collection to make this easier?

```
public class MusicDBInit : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MusicContext db)
    {
        Band bvs = new Band { Name = "Bear vs Shark", Members = 4 };
        Band circa = new Band { Name = "Circa Survive", Members = 4 };
        Band dam = new Band { Name = "Damiera", Members = 3 };

        db.Bands.Add(bvs);
        db.Bands.Add(circa);
        db.Bands.Add(dam);

        base.Seed(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wish to do something like `AddRange` to add many bands in one go?

Comment: I'm not sure about AddRange (I'm just ignorant of its function) but yes, I would like to add several bands in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (as done in `Online Music Store MVC Sample`:

```
 var bands = new List<Band>{
                     new Band { Name = "Bear vs Shark", Members = 4 },
                     new Band { Name = "Circa Survive", Members = 4 },
                     new Band { Name = "Damiera", Members = 3 }
 };


bands.ForEach(x=> db.Bands.Add(x));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.  I kept messing up the syntax while trying this because I was trying to assign each band a variable name in my list, which in retrospect is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that I usually follow is to load in seed data from XML files. A separate class would hold the following:

```
    private XmlNodeList readNodes(String xmlFilePath, String nodeName)
    {
        FileStream reader = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        System.Xml.XmlDocument source = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        source.Load(reader);
        return source.GetElementsByTagName(nodeName);
    }

    public List<Band> readBands(String xmlFilePath)
    {
        List<Band> results = new List<Band>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in readNodes(xmlFilePath, "Band"))
        {
            results.Add(new Band { Members = node.Attributes["members"].Value, Name = node.Attributes["name"].Value });
        }
        results.Sort();
        return results;
    }
```

Then add the following to your `Seed` method:

```
    foreach (Band b in seeder.readBands(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data\\Bands.xml"))
    {
        db.bands.Add(b);
    }
```

Your XML would then look something like this and be located under your App_Data directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bands>
    <band name="Bear vs Shark" members="4" />
    <band name="Circa Survive" members="4" />
    <band name="Damiera" members="3" />
</bands>
```

You could then create seed methods and XML files for every table you'd like to seed. And remember that since you're using `Add` rather than `AddOrUpdate` you will most likely be adding duplicate whenever `Seed` runs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- this is probably a better solution for a larger scale project and for being able to copy seed data over to each new project, but for this particular instance I wanted to iterate over a fairly small data set.